# Counting numbers a AND s = a

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am writing a program to meet the following specifications:

> You have a list of integers, initially the list is empty.
>
> You have to process Q operations of three kinds:
>
> 1. add s: Add integer s to your list, note that an integer can exist
>      more than one time in the list
> 2. del s: Delete one copy of integer s from the list, it's guaranteed
>      that at least one copy of s will exist in the list.
> 3. cnt s: Count how many integers a are there in the list such that a
>      AND s = a , where AND is bitwise AND operator
>
> Additional constraints:
>
> 1 ≤ Q ≤ 200000
>
> 0 ≤ s < 2 ^ 16

I have two approaches but both time out, as the constraints are quite large.

I used the fact that a AND s = a if and only if s has all the set bits of a, and the other bits can be arbitrarily assigned. So we can iterate over all these numbers and increase their count by one.

For example, if we have the number 10:  1010

Then the numbers 1011,1111,1110 will be such that when anded with 1010, they will give 1010. So we increase the count of 10,11,14 and 15 by 1. And for delete we delete one from their respective counts.

Is there a faster method? Should I use a different data structure?

Comment: Which data structure have you used to represent the list of integers? This is an essential information...

Comment: @Renzo, I haven't used a data structure to explicitly store the integers, only an array to store the integers which when anded with the number give the number itself.

Comment: So, how can you add or remove an integer?

Comment: @Renzo, I only need to output the count, so adding and deleting explicitly is immaterial. My output consists only of the counts of the given s.

Comment: And of course, how are you dealing with the multiple-occurrence mandate for the `add` directive. It would seem to me it would be worth trying to brute-force this via `std::unordered_map<int, unsigned int>`, mapping values to their instance counts. The `del` directive would remove the key if the count falls to zero, and the `cnt` command would iterate over the container and, for each hit, add in the mapped count to the running total. Or, I utterly misunderstood the question.

Comment: Suppose input is 10 10 10. Now I add 1 to a[10],a[11],a[14],a[15] each time I encounter a 10. If someone asks me the answer for s = 15, I can simply output a[15]

Comment: So you have an array of 2^16 elements, initially all zeroed, when you add s then you increase a[s] by 1, when delete, decrease a[s] by 1. Is this correct? If the answer is yes, well, then this array is the data structure I was asking for...

Comment: @Renzo, yup that is correct.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is a great resource for sharing your code.

Comment: (I do have? Please state the origin of the problem; if possible, supply a hyperlink.) The upper limit on the number of operations is not big compared to the number of values allowed (not even π times bigger). Try thinking of the value space as having 16 dimensions, if with a low range, each. Please have your example show whether numbers above the current `cnt` query's `s` shall be counted: for `s` = 10(dec), shall the count of 26(dec) be included?(There might be ancient data structures that escaped your attention.)

Comment: @SalvadorDali Could you add a link?

Comment: @stgatilov https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/countercode/challenges/subset

Comment: A pity a good answer has been well presented before the poster (_not_ showing a [Great Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma)) stated the origin of this problem.

Comment: Never edit a question beyond recognition of the first revision answered - ask another one. _If_ you feel justified to edit a question such that an answer becomes invalid, mark this edit as such _in the question proper_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider two ways to solve it that are two slow, and then merge them into one solution, that will be guaranteed to finish in milliseconds.

**Approach 1** (slow)

Allocate an array `v` of size `2^16`. Every time you add an element, do the following:

```cpp
void add(int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 16); ++ i) if ((s & i) == 0) {
        v[s | i] ++;
    }
}
```

(to delete do the same, but decrement instead of incrementing)

Then to answer `cnt s` you just need to return the value of `v[s]`. To see why, note that `v[s]` is incremented exactly once for every number `a` that is added such that `a & s == a` (I will leave it is an exercise to figure out why this is the case).

**Approach 2** (slow)

Allocate an array `v` of size `2^16`. When you add an element `s`, just increment `v[s]`. To query the count, do the following:

```cpp
int cnt(int s) {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 16); ++ i) if ((s | i) == s) {
        ret += v[s & ~i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

(`x & ~y` is a number that has all the bits that are set in `x` that are not set in `y`)

This is a more straightforward approach, and is very similar to what you do, but is written in a slightly different fashion. You will see why I wrote it this way when we combine the two approaches.

Both these approaches are too slow, because in which of them one operation is constant, and one is `O(s)`, so in the worst case, when the entire input consists of the slow operations, we spend `O(Q * s)`, which is prohibitively slow. Now let's merge the two approaches using meet-in-the-middle to get a faster solution.

**Fast approach**

We will merge the two approaches in the following way: `add` will work similarly to the first approach, but instead of considering every number `a` such that `a & s == a`, we will only consider numbers, that differ from `s` only in the lowest 8 bits:

```cpp
void add(int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 8); ++ i) if ((i & s) == 0) {
        v[s | i] ++;
    }
}
```

For delete do the same, but instead of incrementing elements, decrement them.

For counts we will do something similar to the second approach, but we will account for the fact that each `v[a]` is already accumulated for all combinations of the lowest 8 bits, so we only need to iterate over all the combinations of the higher 8 bits:

```cpp
int cnt(int s) {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 8); ++ i) if ((s | (i << 8)) == s) {
        ret += v[s & ~(i << 8)];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now both `add` and `cnt` work in `O(sqrt(s))`, so the entire approach is `O(Q * sqrt(s))`, which for your constraints should be milliseconds.

Pay extra attention to overflows -- you didn't provide the upper bound on `s`, if it is too high, you might want to replace `int`s with `long long`s.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to solve it is to break list of queries in blocks of about *sqrt(S)* queries each. This is a standard approach, usually called *sqrt-decomposition*.

You have to store separately:

1. Array `A[v]`: how much times `s` is present.
2. Array `R[v]`: sum of `A[i]` for all `i` supersets of `v` (i.e. result of *cnt(v)*).
3. List `W` of all changes (*add*, *del* operations) within current block of queries.

**Note:** arrays `A` and `R` are valid only for all the changes from the fully processed block of queries. All the changes that happened within the currently processed block of queries are stored in `W` and are not yet applied to `A` and `R`.

Now we process queries block by block, for each block of queries we do:

1. For each query within block:

   - *add(v)*: store increment for `v` into `W` list.
   - *del(v)*: store decrement for `v` into `W` list.
   - *cnt(v)*: return `R[v] + X(W)`, where `X(W)` is total changed calculated by trivial processing of all the changes in the list `W`.
2. Apply all the changes from `W` to array `A`, clear list `W`.
3. Recalculate completely array `R` from array `A`.

Note that *add* and *del* take *O(1)* time, and *cnt* takes *O(|W|) = O(sqrt(S))* time. So *step 1* takes *O(Q sqrt(S))* time in total.
 *Step 2* takes *O(|W|)* time, which totals in *O(Q)* time overall.

The most important part is *step 3*. We need to implement it in *O(S)*. Given that there are *Q / sqrt(S)* blocks, this would total in *O(Q sqrt(S))* time as wanted.

Unfortunately, recalculating array `S` **can be done in only *O(S log S)* time**. That would mean *O(Q sqrt(S) log (S))* time. If we choose block size *O(sqrt(S log S))*, then overall time is *O(Q sqrt(S log S))*. No perfect, but interesting nonetheless =)

Answer (score 0):

Given the data structure that you described in one of the comments, you could try the following algorithm (I am giving it in pseudo-code):

```
count-how-many-integers(integer s) {
  sum = 0 
  for i starting from s and increasing by 1 until s*2 {
       if (i AND s) == i {
            sum = sum + a[i]
       }
  }
  return sum
}
```

More sophisticated optimizations should be possible in the inner loop to reduce the number of times the test is performed.